# How do I get a class reference from a String in Java?

Tags: java, android

If I need to return a Class instanced based on a String (e.g., creating logic from JSON), how should that be written?

My initial thought was a switch, but in the Android framework's version of Java, it looks like switch statements don't allow Strings.

Next thought was a HashMap:

```
private HashMap<String, Class> classMap = new HashMap<String, Class>();
classMap.put("someClass", SomeClass.class)?
// ... etc
String someString = jsonObject.getString("someProperty");
Class classRef = classMap.get(someString);
SomeSuperClass classInstance = new classRef();
```

This doesn't work. I'd rather not `if/else` down a lengthy list of possibilities.

Comment: No version of Java allows switch statements with strings (except Java 7, but everyone knows that's just a myth to keep us quiet).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("com.yourpackage.YourClass")` Then to instantiate it: `clazz.newInstance();`

Comment: This will return the reference of the Object class not the reference of the Class class.

Comment: @Bhavik the first line Class.forName("...") returns a class reference. The second line instantiates it and creates an object.

Answer (score 1):

You can also load the class with having the constructors parameters.

E.g.

```
public static void load(String p)
    throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException,
    IllegalAccessException{
        Class cl = classLoader.loadClass(p);
        Constructor c = cl.getConstructor(String.class);
        Plugin plug = (Plugin) c.newInstance("myArgument");
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you return the created Plugin instance?

Comment: We can return the created `Plugin` instance but my intention was to display example that you can create instance of the Object though it has constructor with arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach using a map is what I would do (and you'll see it in Factory Pattern implementations). You're just not instantiating the class correctly:

```
Class classRef = classMap.get(someString);
SomeSuperClass classInstance = classRef.newInstance();
```